# Determining Under Which Conditions A Mapping is a Well-defined Homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

This is a continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930683/mapping-generators-to-generators) problem. I have part of a solution, but am unsure it is correct. Allow me to write the problem again:

> Determine the integers $z$ for which $f : \mathbb{Z}/48 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow Z_{36}$ with $f_z(\overline{1})= x^z$, where $x$ is the generator of $Z_{36}$, extends to a well-defined homomorphism.

First of all, it seems that proving this problem requires I prove that

> $f_z$ is a well-defined homomorphism iff $f_z(\overline{b}) = x^{bz}$ and $z$ is such that $36$ divides $48z$.

Being the overly cautious person that I am, I searched the internet for a solution. I found [this](http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/naik/classes/731/60.9.Soln.pdf). This is somewhat embarrassing, but how does $36 | 48z$ imply $3|z$? I can only get $3|4z$.

My second question pertains to proving the above conjecture. I was able to show that $f_z(\overline{b}) = x^{bz}$ and $z$ is such that $36$ divides $48z$ implies $f_z$ is a well-defined homomorphism easily enough. However, I am having trouble with the second direction. Here is my attempt:

Suppose $f_z$ is a well-defined homomorphism with $f_z(\overline{1}) = x^z$. Let $\overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z}/46\mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary. Then by the homomorphism property, we have

$f_z(\overline{b}) = f_z(\overline{1} + \dots + \overline{1}) = f_z(\overline{1}) \dots f_z(\overline{1}) = x^z \dots x^z = x^{bz}$.

Now, we want to show $z$ satisfies $36|48z$. Suppose the contrary, and let $\overline{b} = \overline{b'}$, which implies $b' = b +48k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because $f_z$ is well-defined, we have

$f_z(\overline{b}) = f_z(\overline{b'})$

$x^{bz} = x^{b'z}$

$x^{bz} = x^{(b+48k)z}$

$x^{bz} = x^{bz} (x^{48z})^k$

$e = (x^{48z})^k$,

where we have assumed $x^{48z} \neq e$.

I feel that there is some contradiction lurking in this equations, but I cannot see it.

Comment: To your first question, note that 4 is not divisible by 3. Therefore, in the product $4z$, if 4 isn't divisible by 3, $z$ must be divisible by 3.

Comment: Hmm, no bites? Usually I get a response within a half an hour; perhaps I have been very lucky. I hope no one gets the impression that I am demanding attention now; I am merely wondering if my original post needs clarification. If so, I will gladly clarify.

Comment: I don't understand $f_z(\overline{1})= x^z$. Where did the $x$ come from?

Comment: Your notation is awkward. Why use multiplicative notation for the codomain? Also, there are many generators for $Z_{36}$. So did you mean to define $f_z(1) = z$?

Comment: No, $f_z(\overline{1}) = x^z$, where $z$ is an integer to be determined.